# how to copy/split an inputstream in java?

Tags: java, io, split, copy, inputstream

Is there a way to copy/split an input stream into two input streams similar to apache commons TeeOutputStream?  I am trying to filter some input from the stream while displaying the entire input stream in another thread.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use Apache's TeeOutputStream if it does what you require?

Comment: @fge That was my exact first thought.

Comment: Q: How do I make something that works like X?  A: Use X!

Comment: TeeOutputStream splits a output streams whereas I want to split an input stream.

Answer (score 2):

Use ***org.apache.commons.io.input.TeeInputStream***

Comment: Use this if you want to tee it to a seperate output, otherwise use ProxyInputStream

Answer (score 0):

I would write a InputStreamFilterer class, which took the original InputStream in the constructor.

Offer up two methods for getOriginalStream and getFilteredStream, and wrap the the filtered stream with a proxy / delegate that intercepts the bytes read to take out the data you wish to filter out.

This approach assumes that you want to filter the stream as it's read, and is naive about how you want to use the data. Watch out for character encoding as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the input stream, write it to two different output streams, and read from them.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want [ProxyInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/ProxyInputStream.html)

Example:

```
ProxyInputStream pis = new ProxyInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
```